# quote not having effect with dplyr::mutate and purrr::map2

Tags: r, functional-programming, quote

trying to create function which takes in quoted variables names to mutate data frame before plotting but seem I'm not doing it right when I'm extending it with purrr::map2()

the probelm seem to be coming from the `dplyr::mutate` `case_when()` because the `color_codes` column with `Log2FC_above2` and `Log2FC_below2` tags are not correct in the resulting data frame when i use `map2`

here's example script

```
#####################################################
#### create example data frame ################# 
#####################################################

#function to generate random numbers
random_numb_generator = function(x, numb=25){
    treatment_x1 = runif(n=numb, min=-5, max=5)
    treatment_x2 = runif(n=numb, min=0, max=5)
    return(cbind(treatment_x1,treatment_x2))
}

n_unique_samples <- 5 
ls <- lapply(1:n_unique_samples, random_numb_generator, numb=25) #create a list of random numbers

# convert list to dataframe 
df <- do.call(data.frame, ls)


##rename columns of data frame
names_raw <- c(paste0("treatment_", letters[1:n_unique_samples],1:2),
paste0("treatment_", letters[1:n_unique_samples],c(2,1)))
names(df) <- sort(names_raw)

#add tag 
df <- df %>% mutate(gene.symbol = paste0("gene", row_number()))
```

```
######################################################################
#### make function to mutate table and prepare for plot ################# 
######################################################################
plot_exp <- function(dat_in, y_var, labels_col){
#enquo variables
    y_var <- enquo(y_var)
    y_var_name = quo_name(y_var)
  


  #mutate df to allow plotting
dat_log2 <- dat_in %>% mutate(labels = case_when({{labels_col}} >= abs(2) ~ as.character(gene.symbol),
                                                TRUE ~ ""),
                              color_codes = case_when(labels == "" ~ "Log2FC_below2",
                                                TRUE ~ "Log2FC_above2")) %>% 
                                                select(c({{y_var}}, {{labels_col}}, labels, color_codes, gene.symbol))

#head(dat_log2)
print(paste0("/path/to/save/",{{y_var_name}},".pdf"))
return(dat_log2)
}
```

```
######################################################################
#### unit test function and with purrr::map2 and ################# 
######################################################################

Here test function with two pairs of variables
#works fine
plot_exp(dat_in=df, y_var=treatment_a2, labels_col=treatment_a1)

#create separate vectors
col1 <- sort(names_raw)[str_detect(sort(names_raw),"1")]
col2 <- sort(names_raw)[str_detect(sort(names_raw),"2")]


##works but color_codes, `Log2FC_above2` and `Log2FC_below2` is wrong
map2(col1,col2, ~plot_exp(dat_in=df, y_var=.y, labels_col=.y))
```

Comment: did you mean `map2(col1,col2, ~plot_exp(dat_in=df, y_var=.x, labels_col=.y))` ?
If you're passing variables as character, try injecting them: `~rlang::inject(plot_exp(dat_in=df, y_var=!!sym(.x), labels_col=!!sym(.y)))` ?`

Comment: within dplyr, >=1.2.0,  `map2(col1,col2, ~plot_exp(dat_in=df, y_var=all_of(.x), labels_col=all_of(.y)))` should work too